# Does localPart and payloadRoot depend on address location and operation name in wsdl?

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-ws

I'm trying to create SOAP service via spring-ws. I have prewritten third-party wsdl and I'm generating code from that wsdl (contract first approach) via jaxb plugin.

When I build project spring deploys it on `host/my-app-context/ws/notification` successfully.

**Problem** - When I make request via SOAP UI I'm seeing `No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://other.company.kz/service/}SendMessage]`.

Note 1. http://other.company.kz/service it's third-party namespace in given wsdl. **My host where ws is deployed doesn't same with it**

Note 2. The only opeartion in wsdl is `<wsdl:operation name="SendMessage">`

**Does payloadRoot and localPart configs in my endpoint shoud be the same with third-party package and operation name accordingly or they should be same with my hostname/deploy-url?**  I tried   `@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "sendMessage")` where `NAMESPACE_URI` is address location of my service (from wsdl), I also tried NAMESPACE_URI from wsdl namespace (other.company.kz) but both of them are failed.

My Config code looks like

```
@Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

  @Bean(name = "notification")
    public Wsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition() {
        SimpleWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("notification.wsdl"));
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }
```

quote from wsdl

```
<wsdl:binding name="SomeBinding" type="tns0:bla-bla-bla">
        <binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="SendMessage">
            <operation soapAction=""/>
            <wsdl:input name="SendMessageRequest">
                <body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="SendMessageResponse">
                <body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="sendMessageFault">
                <fault name="sendMessageFault" namespace="" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="SomeService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns0:SomeBinding" name="SomePort">
            <address location="http://myhost/my-app-context/ws/notification"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
```

my endpoint

```
@Endpoint
public class MailEndpoint {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "I tried myhost (address location in wsdl) and other-company"

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "sendMessage")
    @ResponsePayload
    public SyncSendMessageResponse sendMessage(@RequestPayload SyncSendMessageRequest request) {
        SyncSendMessageResponse response = new SyncSendMessageResponse();
        ResponseData responseData = new ResponseData();
        responseData.setResult("sync");
        response.setResponseData(responseData);
        return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue when implementing a ws-server. In my case, when no ws-security was used, the  **@PayloadRoot** used to work fine.

When I applied ws-security, I used to have endpoint not found and my solution was to rely on [@SoapAction](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/soap/server/endpoint/annotation/SoapAction.html).

My understanding at the time was:

- The headers will not be encrypted so the soapaction is the header will be not be encrypted
- The payload interceptor seems to fails because it is maybe too early in the process (before the message is decrypted)

Comment: I'm not using ws-security and mapping doesn't work. What did you put into your namespace, deployment url or wsdl namespace?

Comment: Do you have a targetNamespace in your wsdl ?

Comment: Yes, I have targetNamespace

Comment: NAMESPACE_URI should be your target namespace